# How to convert actix_web::web::Bytes to json?

Tags: json, rust, actix-web

This is my code:

```rust
#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let mut client = Client::default();

    // Create request builder and send request
    let response = client
        .get("https://ipapi.co/localhost/json")
        .header("User-Agent", "actix-web/3.0")
        .send() // <- Send request
        .await; // <- Wait for response
    let result = response.unwrap().body().await.unwrap();
    println!("Response: {:?}", result);


}
```

**This code works, but I don't know how to convert type `actix_web::web::Byte` to json.**

I have tried to convert it ti json:

```rust
    let result = response
        .unwrap()
        .json::<HashMap<String, std::marker::PhantomData<String>>>()
        .await;
```

But every time I'm receiving an error, because HashMap has mixed types. It is HashMap<String, bool|String|i32>.

So my question is:

How to convert response to json?

I'm using `use actix_web::client::Client`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`serde_json::value::Value`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/value/enum.Value.html)

```rust
use serde_json::value::Value;

...

let result = response
        .unwrap()
        .json::<HashMap<String, Value>>()
        .await;
```

Comment: Alternatively, define a *precise* deserialisable structure so each value is matched to a properly typed field instead of having to dump everything into a hashmap.